# Legacy MFC application not running properly on windows7 OS with Aero theme but behaving fine with Classic theme

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-7, mfc

We have one MFC application which is developed on visual studio 2008 professional edition with VC9.0 compiler. The application runs fine on windows server 2003, windows xp and 2008 R2 OS. When I run it on windows7 (with default Aero theme) then it behaves strangely, But by applying classic theme on windows7 then it is running fine. What could be the reason behind this? Can anybody clarify?

Do i need to recompile the application by adding required changes to support it on windows7 OS? what would be those changes, please provide any reference link on msdn.

Comment: Strangely = how? Is it using deprecated or undocumented functionality? Does it depend on things (values/behavior) that are different in Aero?

Comment: The application window must show the cellgrids (created by using Draw3dRect() call) which are missing, but if i change the zoom value to below 80% then it is showing up. and one more strange thing is the dockable window displayed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in your program: most likely somewhere in the code it is relying on some OS function doing something in a particular way, which has held true in the past, but isn't guaranteed by the function's documentation, and is now behaving differently with Aero.

Sorry that this isn't very helpful, but there's no easy way round it: you're going to have to try to narrow down the problem and debug it. That's just how it is.